# Using playFramework tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, playframework-1.x

How do I use playWork tags with JavaScript?
This did't work. Any other solution?

```
$.each(${specs}, function(i, v) {
addNewSizeLine(v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to see the `${specs}` variable to be able to answer this better, but I think you need to turn this into a javascript array.

```
var jsSpecs = [#{list items: specs, as: 'spec' } '${spec}', #{/list}];

$.each(jsSpecs, function(i, v) {
addNewSizeLine(v);
});
```